# p:progressBar animation does not match the value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, progress-bar

I use a progress bar in my code like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['start.reindex']}"
                 widgetVar="reIndex"
                 action="#{generalConfigBean.reBuildIndex}"
                 onclick="PF('pbAjax').start(); PF('reIndex').disable();"
                 style="margin-left:25px;"/>

<p:progressBar id="progressBarPanel"
               widgetVar="pbAjax"
               ajax="true"
               value="#{generalConfigBean.progress}"
               labelTemplate="{value}% #{msg['reindex.msg']}"
               global="false"
               styleClass="animated"
               interval="10"
               style=" width: 100px; margin-left: 40px;">

    <p:ajax event="complete" oncomplete="PF('reIndex').enable(); PF('pbAjax').cancel();"/>
</p:progressBar>
```

and generalConfigBean is like this:

```
public class GeneralConfigBean extends BaseBean {

    private Integer progress;

    public void reBuildIndex() {
        if (API.reIndex()) {
            showMessage("reindex.successful", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        } else {
            showMessage("reindex.failed", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        }
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer reIndexPercentage) {
        this.progress = reIndexPercentage;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        progress = API.reIndexPercentage();
        System.out.println(progress);
        return progress;
    }
}
```

When I click the button, value of progress bar increases until 100% and it matches `reBuildIndex()`, and when it reaches 100% the button will be enabled. But the animation in progress bar does not match the value and even when `reBuildIndex` is done progress bar animation still works!

Image below shows it:

[image]

Comment: What is the functional requirement? It seems you need a [`<p:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml) or [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf) instead.

Comment: your view code seems fine. try increasing interval value and check if it cause any differences.

Comment: when i increase interval it will be okay. but because interval is big, progress bar show only 0% and then 100%. i think There must be a better way.

Comment: @Tiny : No! i exactly need a progress bar.

Comment: @zsh have you found the solution of the problem? I am facing the same issue. Is it a bug in Primefaces?

Comment: @Ankit no :( the only solution i found was increasing interval value

Comment: same issue ... and still no soluion :(